# perl - using mysql - out of memory

Tags: mysql, perl

I am trying to do a simple thing with perl but I have hard time doing it. I have to read data from mysql do something on the data and then print something. The problem is that the size of my database file is only 90MB and my system has 4GB of memory. Could anyone help me with this issue? I mean why is that?

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use common::sense;
use File::Slurp;
use Text::SpeedyFx;
use DBI;
use DBD::mysql;
my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:mysql:enron','x','y') or die "Connection Error:     $DBI::errstr\n";

# Create cascades
my $sql = "select uniqueid,mid,sender,receiver,unixdate,body,seen from     filteredmessage";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";

# Variables
my $row; 
my $uniqueId;
my $msg1;
my $sender;
my $receiver;
my $unixdate;

my $uniqueId2;
my $msg2;
my $sender2;
my $receiver2;
my $unixdate2;
my $dif;
my $row2;
my $sql2;
my $sth2;
my $j;

my $i=1;
while ($row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
    my $flagSingleRow = 0;
    $uniqueId = $row->{'uniqueid'};
    $msg1 = $row->{'body'};
    $sender = $row->{'sender'};
    $receiver = $row->{'receiver'};
    $unixdate = $row->{'unixdate'};

    $sql2 = "select uniqueid,mid,sender,receiver,unixdate,body,seen from filteredmessage";
    $sth2 = $dbh->prepare($sql2);
    $sth2->execute or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";

    $j=1;
    while ($row2 = $sth2->fetchrow_hashref) {
        $uniqueId2 = $row2->{'uniqueid'};
        $msg2 = $row2->{'body'};
        $sender2 = $row2->{'sender'};
        $receiver2 = $row2->{'receiver'};
        $unixdate2 = $row2->{'unixdate'};

        $dif = cosine_similarity($sfx->hash_fv($msg1, 8192),$sfx->hash_fv($msg2, 8192));
        #if($dif>0.5){
            print $i." ".$j." ". $dif."\n";
        #}
        $j++;
    }
    $i++;
} 

sub cosine_similarity {
    my ($a, $b) = @_;

    my $nbits_a = unpack(q(%32b*) => $a);
    my $nbits_b = unpack(q(%32b*) => $b);

    return $nbits_a * $nbits_b
        ? unpack(q(%32b*) => $a & $b) / sqrt $nbits_a * $nbits_b
        : 0;
}
```

Comment: You're trying to compare every row of the table with every other row? This calls `cosine_similarity` N^2 times. But you're not accumulating any data as far as I can tell, I don't see why this should cause a memory problem.

Comment: Exactly. That's why I am curious. I don't know why I keep receiving this error !!!

Comment: Consider `{RaiseError => 1}`.  That would implicitly take care of the `or die ... $DBI::errstr` checks you make, and the checks you omit (as after a `prepare()`).

Comment: Not enough information.  Please provide an exact error message and [sscce](http://sscce.org).  What runs out of memory, perl or mysqld?  Are you doing something naive with File::Slurp?  What about `$sfx`, whose construction you don't show above?  Does your perl process have the resources to hold three copies of your result set in memory (see [`mysql_use_result` in the docs](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-mysql/lib/DBD/mysql.pm#mysql_use_result))?  Etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text::SpeedyFx leaks memory badly.  Here's a simple demonstration how hashing the same thing results in memory growth.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use v5.12;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::SpeedyFx;

my $sfx = Text::SpeedyFx->new;

for(1..1_000) {
    $sfx->hash_fv("12345", 8192);
}

say `ps auwx $$`;

for(1..10_000) {
    $sfx->hash_fv("12345", 8192);
}

say `ps auwx $$`;

for(1..100_000) {
    $sfx->hash_fv("12345", 8192);
}

say `ps auwx $$`;

for(1..1_000_000) {
    $sfx->hash_fv("12345", 8192);
}

say `ps auwx $$`;

$ perl ~/tmp/test.plx
USER      PID  %CPU %MEM      VSZ    RSS   TT  STAT STARTED      TIME COMMAND
schwern 81574  29.1  0.1  2463756   8412 s000  S+    1:58AM   0:00.21 perl /Users/schwern/tmp/test.plx

USER      PID  %CPU %MEM      VSZ    RSS   TT  STAT STARTED      TIME COMMAND
schwern 81574  54.4  0.2  2463756  18000 s000  S+    1:58AM   0:00.22 perl /Users/schwern/tmp/test.plx

USER      PID  %CPU %MEM      VSZ    RSS   TT  STAT STARTED      TIME COMMAND
schwern 81574  70.2  1.4  2553868 118384 s000  S+    1:58AM   0:00.35 perl /Users/schwern/tmp/test.plx

USER      PID  %CPU %MEM      VSZ    RSS   TT  STAT STARTED      TIME COMMAND
schwern 81574  98.5 13.4  3561496 1122320 s000  S+    1:58AM   0:01.49 perl /Users/schwern/tmp/test.plx
```

That works out to about 1K per call to hash_v.  Since 1K is the bit vector size, it indicates SpeedyFx is storing every call to hash_v separately rather than reusing the same slot for the same octets.

I have [reported this as a bug](https://github.com/creaktive/Text-SpeedyFx/issues/2).  Meanwhile, to mitigate the problem you can initialize the Text::SpeedyFx object inside the outer loop.

Comment: Fixed in [v0.12 of the module](https://metacpan.org/release/SYP/Text-SpeedyFx-0.012). Thanks for providing detailed info about the issue!

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `$sth2->finish` before you reuse `$sth2` for a new query. (eg,

```
    }
    $sth2->finish;
    $i++;
}
```

)

Also my second comment is that your function `cosine_similarity` is symmetric (ie, `cosine_similarity(x,y) = cosine_similarity(y,x)`).  So you could cut down almost 50% of your time if you add an `ORDER BY uniqueid` to `$sql` and make the appropriate change to `$sql2` to only fetch rows where `uniqueid >= $uniqueId`.

Comment: @nimafl, should you also initialize `$sfx` first outside of the while-loop with `$sfx = Text::SpeedyFx->new`?

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to use 'fetchrow_arrayref' instead of 'fetchrow_hashref' on both the statement handles? You will then have to get your values using specific array indices rather than hash keys.

```
while ($row = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref) {
    my $flagSingleRow = 0;
    $uniqueId = $row->[0];
    $msg1 = $row->[1];
    $sender = $row->[2];
    $receiver = $row->[3];
    $unixdate = $row->[4];
...
# and similarly for $sth2
```

The actual position of each field in the array depends on the order of columns in the select statement.
Give this a shot and let us know the results.

Comment: Nope
I don't think this is the solution either

Comment: @nimafl This is an interesting problem. Is it possible to do a more involved debugging. Basically, insert debugging print statements at various parts in the code, and fire the script. When the process crashes, the last printed error message might give us a clue as to where the memory leak is occurring. Another option is to run the script through the debugger and jump to strategic points in the program (avoid large loops), until the program crashes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the main problem with my program is using $sfx->hash_fv. I have to come up with some ideas to improve this function. This is not my own function and it comes from the SpeedyFx package. Thank you guys anyway.